# Diagram to represents words having as many $0$ as $1$

Tags: turing-machines

> Give the diagram of transitions of a Turing machine to a ribbon which
> accepts the language on the alphabet $\{0, 1\}$ of the words which contain
> as many $0$ as of $1$. (Note well that the $0$ and the $1$ can appear in any
> order.)

This problem is similar to $\{0^n 1^n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ except the fact that we mix up all the $0$'s and $1$'s and can be solved with a simple pushdown automata. An instance of an accepting word on the tape would be $010011000111$ and a rejecting word would be $010111$.

I am confused how to set that up. I have thought building a transition with two states :

1. $q_0$ would be the starting starting which is also the accepting state.
2. $q_1$ would be the rejecting state.

I have thought using the transition function which will move left when I meet a $0$, move right when I meet a $1$ and using the symbol $\\\$$ whenever a state has been visited.

Am I on the right track? How to build such diagram?

Comment: Please don't delete your question after receiving a question.  Part of our mission is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers, that will be useful to others as well.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4097007/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/138790/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

The starting state must be different than the accepting state or you will end up accepting all words.

As for an indication to solve your problem, you should consider multiple states of the Turing Machine:

- searching for a $0$ or a $1$;
- already encountered a $0$ (replaced with a special symbol $\\\$$), searching for a $1$ to replace it with $\\\$$;
- already encountered a $1$ (replaced with a special symbol $\\\$$), searching for a $0$ to replace it with $\\\$$;
- returning to the beginning of the word.

If, when searching specifically for a $0$ or a $1$ (in the two middle states), you encounter a blank symbol, it means that you reached the end of the word without encountering one of the searched symbol, so you can reject the word. If, when searching for either a $0$ or a $1$ (the first state) you encounter a blank symbol, it means you already replaced all $0$'s and $1$'s with $\\\$$'s, so you can accept the input.

Here's [a way to do it](http://turingmachinesimulator.com/shared/opudpbxqlk), with the previous 4 states (with 2 additionnal states for accepting and rejecting). Note that there may be more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure how to deal with having the exact same number of $0$'s and $1$'s. This is the implicit memory which manages that, but I don't understand how to handle it. It is easy  with a pushdown automata because we can use a stack, but it is not all that clear how to do it with the turing machine. Can you help with that?

Comment: There is no infinite memory here other than the tape. Each time you encounter a $0$, you do not replace other $0$'s until you have encountered a $1$, and reciprocally.

Comment: Oooh, I understand now! Thanks!

Comment: When I am going left on the tape, how to I know I have reached the beginning? I have thought placing an # at the beginning as an indicator I have reached the beginning.

Comment: Since you replace $0$'s and $1$'s with $\$$, you know that when going left, you will be at the beginning when encountering the first blank symbol (there will be no blank symbols in the middle of the input).

Comment: I have tried something with JFLAP. I will put my try in the question in a few seconds. Can you tell me if the diagram is fine?

Comment: That seems alright.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Very helpful! :D